# How to add specific characters in between values of a JavaScript date?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a date in JavaScript to fit a specific format.

My desired format is `29-Jan-2021`

With the below code I have managed to generate `"29 Jan 2021"`:

```js
var newDate = new Date('2021-01-29T12:18:48.6588096Z')

const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
};

console.log(newDate.toLocaleString('en-UK', options))
```

Can someone please show me how I can add `-` between the day, month, & year in the date above?

Comment: Simply take your date string and do `.replaceAll(" ", "-")`.

Comment: When I run the code, I don't get any quotation marks.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, I was running it here https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-date-in-javascript.html, & the quotation marks were appearing. I've upated my question to remove that aspect. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript); specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/215552), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803/215552)

Comment: You could simply use the date as it is and split it on spaces to reformat it as you want in.
date = Date().split(" ")
console.log(date[2] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[3])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you if you have already able to find the string close to your answer you can achieve your solution with either of the two methods.

Either you can use **replaceAll()** or **replace()**. Both will be able to solve the issue.

```
let dateFormat = "29 Jan 2021"
console.log(dateFormat.replaceAll(" ","-")) // 29-Jan-2021
console.log(dateFormat.replace(/ /g,"-")) // 29-Jan-2021
```

Well I would suggest you to use replace() over replaceAll as some browsers do not support replaceAll(). Do check replaceAll support.